# Selector color not showing in custom ListView (pic)

Tags: android, listview, coding-style, listview-selector

I've added a custom style to my `ListView`, but now a few odd things are happening.

> 1)When I click an item on the list, the selector(alt color) doesn't
>   appear. Instead. The standard green selector comes up but it's BEHIND
>   the rounded edges of each row in the list. It's as if the default
>   ListView with standard black rows is bleeding out behind my styled`enter code here`
>   one. Any ideas on how to fix this? Has anybody ever encountered
>   similar issues while working with custom ListViews?
>
> 2)When I fling through the list, the background color changes back to
>   standard Black, and is no longer blue as I designed.

So basically those two are the issues I'm facing right now, the selector not showing up and the black background "bleeding" out behind my grey row as I fling through the list.
Any help/guidance on this issue would be great appreciated, thanks! I've attached a pic

Here is my listview_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dip" 
android:background="@drawable/listview_background"


>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgViewLogo"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/imgview_drawable" >

</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgViewLogo"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#43c6db"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgViewLogo"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="TextView" >
 </TextView>










</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my main ListView layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#708090"
>



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvAlbumList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"

    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

     >




</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally here is my selector.xml, which is a State list drawable

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_pressed"/>

<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_normal" />

</selector>
```

[1]: https://p.twimg.com/AiLoEMVCAAIz_6E.png ""

Comment: You are using the xml layout or  u making it dynamic ?

Comment: I'm doing it via XML. I've added the attribute    listSelector=@drawable/custom_selector to my ListView tag but to no avail.

Comment: Can you post your Listview xml code?

Comment: also **post your selector XML file** for your second problem try to set  listview cacheColorHint to transparent.

Comment: i go with @Frankenstein he is right :)

Comment: Thank you @Frankenstein, I've added set the cacheColorHint to transparent as you suggested and solved my second issue :). I've added code to see if I can get some clarity on my first issue and why my selector is not showing when I click on an item on my list.

Comment: Actually my selector is showing, but it's showing up BEHIND the background of my list item ie; behind the rounded grey boxed rows. Any thoughts on this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

just try to set list selector "null" or remove list selector.

And  instead of setting list selector  set  selector on your custom list row view in adapter.